# Insert days between 2 date into database

Tags: php, sql, date

I have 2 date input in html

```
<tr>
    <td>Value Date</td>
    <td><input type='date' name='valueDate' class='form-control'></td>                  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Maturity Date</td>
    <td><input type='date' name='maturityDate' class='form-control'></td>                   
</tr>
```

and this for action code

```
$valueDate = $_POST['valueDate'];
$maturityDate = $_POST['maturityDate'];
```

right now, i have a variable `$days` for days between 2 date, and thats initial like this :

```
$days = date_diff($valueDate,$maturityDate);
```

and this my query :

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO placement(
                        valueDate, 
                        maturityDate,
                        days
                        ) VALUES(
            '$valueDate',
            '$maturityDate',
            '$days'
            )");
```

im using **PHP 7.2.0** for using `date_diff`.

Before, i try to use `$days->format("%a");`

but i get error. Any idea?

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: This code is not safe, read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Dave this is the error
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\notapembukuan\action1.php on line 15

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\notapembukuan\action1.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\notapembukuan\action1.php on line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

```
//$d1=new DateTime("2018-07-08"); 
$d1=new DateTime($_POST['valueDate']);
//$d2=new DateTime("2018-10-08"); 
$d2=new DateTime($_POST['maturityDate']);
$interval = $d2->diff($d1)->days;
```

https://ideone.com/hpkfxq

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$date1 = new DateTime($_POST['valueDate']);
$date2 = new DateTime($_POST['maturityDate']);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
```

Comment: `$date1` is a string - why do you expect it to have any method?

Comment: Good point, I'll amend that now, completely forgot to add it in!

Comment: @Alex I see you beat me too it! could using something like `DateTime::createFromFormat ` be of use here? or am I trying too hard to over complicate it

Comment: Just continue your efforts and check your code before you post.  I would suggest you to use different online tools to debug and check your code. ideone.com is one of those - just try and debug whatever idea you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
 $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
 $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```